# How to split string and get the extension from the string?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this URL:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/faithmeetslove-d4d6a.appspot.com/o/UserPictures%2FIMG-20210331-WA0005.jpg?alt=media&token=0933dc1a-4881-4ba1-90ac-2556f6dd8eff
```

IN MY FIRESTORE AND HOW CAN I SLIP IT SO THAT I WILL GET THE EXTENSION ".JPG" from the url....

If I can get the extension I will be able to perform function with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without any 3rd party packages like this:

```
var imgUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/faithmeetslove-d4d6a.appspot.com/o/UserPictures%2FIMG-20210331-WA0005.jpg?alt=media&token=0933dc1a-4881-4ba1-90ac-2556f6dd8eff";
 
 String getExtensionFromUrl(String url) =>
   url.split('?').first.split('.').last;

var ext = getExtensionFromUrl(imgUrl);
print(ext);
// OUTPUT: jpg
```

How does it work?

First we split the url by the `?`, because we want to seperate the base url from the query parameters. (query paramteres)

If our url is: `www.google.com/image.jpg?parameter=xxxxx`, `split('?')` will return a list that looks like this: `['www.google.com/image.jpg', 'parameter=xxxxx']`.
Then we take the first element of that list, by calling the `.first` getter.

We split the first element by `.` and we get another list that looks like this: `['www', 'google', 'com', '/image', 'jpg']`. Now we just have to get the last element of this new list and we do that by calling the  `.last` getter on it.

Comment: Thanks You are the man

Comment: I hope it helped you. :)

Comment: yes it helped me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extension` function in the `path` package to get the extension from a file path:

```
final extension = p.extension(path);
```

https://pub.dev/packages/path

*How can I use this as a switch?*

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
var path = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/faithmeetslove-d4d6a.appspot.com/o/UserPictures%2FIMG-20210331-WA0005.jpg?alt=media&token=0933dc1a-4881-4ba1-90ac-2556f6dd8eff"
var ext = p.extension(path);
if(ext == ".jpeg")
   ...
else
   ...
```

Comment: thanks for this answer but how can i check if it contain .jpeg so that i can show another widget

Comment: Expanded my answer